# How to make this UI of tabs with tapView in Flutter

Tags: flutter

This is taps with tab views

I want to make the selected tap to not have border on the bottom , and also I'm not able to have border radius on topLeft and topRight only with custom border, I'm getting this error:A borderRadius can only be given on borders with uniform colors and styles.

Can this be done by custom painter?
[image]

Comment: can you share what you have done so far?